# why are these strings being considered equal ? python

Tags: python, string, if-statement

Don't know what else to say.
running this code:

```
print (browser.current_url)
    if (str(browser.current_url) == "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox" or "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/"):
        return(1)
    else:
        return(2)
```

getting this output (note the `browser.current_url` printed in the output. it is clearly not equal to the two urls i am checking against in my `if` statement. what am I doing wrong ?

```
https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/challenge/pwd?
1
```

Comment: Use `if browser.current_url in ("https:...","https:/..."):`.

Comment: Careful posting auth related url parameters into SO, they can have sensitive tokens etc.  Nothing in your code prints out `1`.  So update your question to include a complete , reproducible example.

Comment: oh that one is just from a print return code statement that is in another function.